# Configuring filezilla to run ftp over a home network

Tags: file-transfer, ftp

### Background

I want to be able to ftp from one of my computers to a directory on the others.

My PC is running xampp and has ample space whereas my netbook doesn't. I can already access the xampp directory locally over my home network and want to be able to upload / download from it (over the home network)

I've installed filezilla server and got that up and running on the main machine. I want to be able to log in to it from the netbook but am unable to do so.

### Currently

1. filezilla server is running on my PC and listening on port 21.
2. I've created a user with a password to login as.
3. I can log in fine on the main machine using (localhost, username, password)

I'm unable to login from the netbook via 192.168.0.3:21 using the same login credentials.

Comment: This Question is quite unclear, please edit to clarify. 192.168.0.3 is the host running FileZilla and this host can be reached from the other one (same network, ping works)? Since you mention login credentials: Connecting works and credentials are refused? So what error message do you get?

Comment: sorry 192.168.0.3 is the lan ip address of the computer running filezilla server. It is pingable from the netbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is... Check your firewall!

This has caught me out more times than I care to say...

FTP requires port 21 as well as passive ports... either configure these yourself or try to exclude the FTP server program itself in Windows Firewall or whatever firewall you are using.

Comment: disabling the firewall for LAN connections worked, so I just need to re-enable it and configure an exception. Cheers.